# Laravel morph query join relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to do a join statement on a query that has a morph relationship and I need to select the first image row and a field which is images.small but I'm getting the following error.

Query:

```
Movie::select(['id', 'images.small as poster', 'title', 'release_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])->join('images', function($join) {
    $join->on('images.imageable_id', '=', 'movie.id')
        ->where('images.imageable_type', '=', 'App\Movie')->first();
})
```

Error:

(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on `images`.`imageable_id` = `movie`.`id` and `images`.`imageable_type` = ? limi' at line 1 (SQL: select * on `images`.`imageable_id` = `movie`.`id` and `images`.`imageable_type` = App\Movie limit 1)

Comment: This `App\Movie` shows your model? See your where condition! You make it with your model!! Why?